# Looking for a set like the fat Cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

**Problem:**

> Assume $0 < \epsilon < 1$ and $\mu_{\mathcal L}$ is the Lebesgue measure. Find a measurable set $A \subset [0, 1]$ such that the closure of $A$ is $[0, 1]$ and $\mu_{\mathcal L}(A) = \epsilon$.

**My Attempt:**

I quickly started reading about the fat Cantor set, whose essential feature (as far as I know) is that its measure can be any such $\epsilon$. But I think the fatal flaw is that the fat Cantor set is closed, whereas I need a set whose closure is $[0, 1]$.

I don't know where to look for a solution. Can I fiddle with fat Cantor sets and solve this problem or do I need a fundamentally different approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the complement of a fat Cantor set?

Comment: @fwd No, but thanks for giving me something to think about.

Comment: You can take any subset with measure $\epsilon$ and add any remaining rationals.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, if I take a fat Cantor set of Lebesgue measure epsilon, say $C_{\epsilon}$, and then consider $C_{\epsilon} \cup \mathbb Q$ (in $[0, 1]$), then by adding the rationals I have not changed the measure, and because the rationals are dense, the closure has to be $[0, 1]$? Is that about right?

Comment: I guess I might need to change $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q \setminus C_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Yes. But you do not need to so fancy as to use a Cantor set. $[0,\epsilon]$ will do.

Comment: Wow, I guess I'm over-complicating this. So I can just use $(0, \epsilon) \cup (\mathbb Q \setminus (0, \epsilon))$. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest example is something like
$$A = [0,\varepsilon] \cup \left( \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \right). $$
That is, pick your favorite set of measure $\varepsilon$, then throw in the rational numbers.  The rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (and therefore dense in $[0,1]$), but have zero measure.  Thus
$$\varepsilon = \mu([0,\varepsilon]) \le \mu(A) \le \mu([0,\varepsilon]) + \mu(\mathbb{Q}) = \varepsilon + 0 = \varepsilon, $$
but $\overline{A} = [0,1]$, which seems to be the desired result.

---

Another interesting set is something like the following:

> Let $\{q_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and let
> $$ B_j = B(q_j, \varepsilon 2^{-j-1}) $$
> denote the (open) ball of radius $2^{-j-1}$ (i.e diameter $2^{-j}$) centered at $q_j$.  Take $A$ to be the union of these balls, i.e.
> $$ A = [0,1] \cap \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j. $$
> Observe that, thanks to the countable subadditivity of the measure, the measure of $A$ is bounded above by $\varepsilon$:
> $$ \mu(A)
> = \mu\left( \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} B_j \right)
> \le \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_j)
> = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \varepsilon 2^{-j}
> = \varepsilon.$$
> Moreover, $A$ contains all of the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, so its closure is $[0,1]$.

This example does not *quite* meet the requirements of the problem (we cannot really bound the measure of the set from below, as the balls may overlap, or may not be entirely contained in $[0,1]$), but it is (I think) an interesting example of what can happen—this is an *open* set which has measure as small as we like, which is nevertheless dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm just going to try to verify the details of this, since I'm a measure theory noob, but it looks good. Thanks.